# MS SQL "SELECT INTO" table creation issues

Tags: sql-server

I need to modify an MS SQL "job" and add a step.  I am creating the step in SSMS to test what I am doing.  I am on a DEV server.

I need to do a `SELECT INTO` to create or populate a table.  The only complication is that the `FROM` clause references a "Linked Server" that is Oracle.  The basic query is:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable
FROM LinkedServer..RemoteSchema.RemoteTable
```

I get two errors reported in SSMS:

- No matter what I call the "new" local table SSMS reports that it is an invalid object.
- I am told that there is a syntax error near `FROM`

In the existing DB job there are several examples of this sort of usage.  I am just not sure why it is failing here.

What have I tried?  I have tried the following in SSMS on my desktop and RDP'd into the DEV server as an 'admin' user to use SSMS there.

```
SELECT *
INTO MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable
FROM LinkedServer..RemoteSchema.RemoteTable

--

USE MyDatabase;

SELECT *
INTO MySchema.MyTable
FROM LinkedServer..RemoteSchema.RemoteTable

--

SELECT *
INSERT INTO  MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, '
    select * from RemoteSchema.RemoteTable
');

--

SELECT *
INTO MyDatabase.MySchema.foo
FROM MyDatabase.MySchema.ExistingTable
```

In the last instance above I am making sure that the source table exists and that the target table does not.  I *think* I am following the rules from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

What I was missing was a giant typo.  I was actually using incorrect syntax like the third example above: `select * INSERT into...`.  I was blind to the word "INSERT" in my SSMS query window and managed to edit it out of most of the examples above.

Comment: `SELECT * INSERT INTO` is incorrect.. it's always `Select * Into`  or if the tables exists, you can use `Insert into [t] Select * from`

Comment: Doh! How did that "insert" get in there?

Comment: I can't actually replicate the behaviour you're describing. Although against a SQL Server that is a linked instance, using a `SELECT * INTO...FROM...` statement with 4 part naming for the `FROM` does not cause an error.

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour either. There has to be something in your actual code that is causing the syntax error and invalid object error that isn't reproduced in what you've given us.

Comment: Thanks all.  @JamieD77 caught it.  I was using `select * INSERT into...`.  I was totally blind to that word.  Somehow I had edited it out of most of the examples above but it was glaring at me in the query window of SSMS.  Sorry to take up your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an empty table and then insert rows from the linked server into the table.

```
Create table  #MyTable (
col1
, col2 ...
);

INSERT INTO #MyTable (col1, col2 ...)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM LinkedServer..RemoteSchema.RemoteTable
```